# Efficient way for a host-to-Qemu communication

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu

I am basically trying to coordinate two processes, one inside Qemu (**user-mode**) and one is on the host machine. Right now I am looking for some methods to setup this virtual-to-host communication.

I understood that `TCP/UDP` would always work. Nevertheless, is there any more efficient methods? I tried to search if Qemu itself provided some specific way for such a communication, but so far no positive findings.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like what you are looking for is [vsock](https://wiki.qemu.org/Features/VirtioVsock) which provides a bi-directional socket like interface between host and guest using an efficient virtio implamenation.

Comment: Thank you for the info! However, to be more specific, I am indeed looking for an efficient communication strategy between `user-mode qemu` and the host. Do you happen to know any technique like that?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am just humbly guessing it could be slow...?

Comment: only in so far as any translation incurs overhead. However once the user-space application makes the system call it's all down to host performance as the data is sent by the host kernel.